# struct inside a class that has a pointer to a function requires forward declaration of functions outside of the class?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, forward-declaration

I have a private struct in my class Menu that contains menu item attributes. one of those attributes is a pointer to a function. It seems as though what I have written works when I forward declare functions outside the class, but having functions defined outside the class seems like very bad practice.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

//forward declaration outside the class
void completelyRandom();//does not throw error
class Menu
{

private:
    typedef void(*Menu_Processing_Function_Ptr)();

    struct MenuItem
    {
        unsigned int  number;
        const char *  text;
        Menu_Processing_Function_Ptr p_processing_function;
    };

    MenuItem menu[] =
    {
        {1, "Completely random", completelyRandom}

    };

public:
    Menu();

    ~Menu();
};
```

And here is some code that throws the error but is closer to what I hope is possible:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>


class Menu
{

private:
    typedef void(*Menu_Processing_Function_Ptr)();

    struct MenuItem
    {
        unsigned int  number;
        const char *  text;
        Menu_Processing_Function_Ptr p_processing_function;
    };

    MenuItem menu[1] =
    {
        {1, "Completely random", completelyRandom}

    };

public:
    Menu();
    //declaration within the class
void completelyRandom();//does throw error
    ~Menu();
};
```

I have tried moving the completelyRadom() declaration all around within the Menu scope, but get the error

`a value of type "void (Menu::*)()" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "Menu::Menu_Processing_Function_Ptr"`

Is there a way I can forward declare the function that would be within best practices? Or should I regret my poor design choices and start all over?

Comment: The only error in the code you show is that you can't define arrays without a size. You must specify the size of the `menu` array. Which is also the only error shown [here](https://godbolt.org/z/hVvdBR) (it disappears if you set the size of the array). So please create a proper [mcve] which we can copy and replicate the problem ourselves.

Comment: Not if you provide an initialization list. In this case a size of 1 is implied.

Comment: Not for in-class inline initializations, as [incomplete types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type) are not allowed in classes. See also [this non-static data member reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members).

Comment: The second example you show should indeed give the error you say, and that's because pointers to non-member functions are not equal to pointers to member functions. A (non-static) member function needs an object to be called on (what becomes `this` inside the function), this is implicitly passed as a hidden first argument. Non-member function doesn't have that.

Comment: I see. It did not occur to me to search for "pointer to a member function" rather than "pointer to a function." A quick check seems to have provided a solution -- i'll give it a shot tomorrow as I am about to fall asleep. Will post the solution for others to see if everything is hunky dory. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

"Non-static member functions (instance methods) have an implicit parameter (the this pointer) which is the pointer to the object it is operating on, so the type of the object must be included as part of the type of the function pointer. " - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer

check this code for an example:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Menu
{

private:
    //By specifying the class type for the pointer -> 'Menu::' in this case 
    // we no longer have to forward declare the functions
    //outside of the class
    typedef void(Menu::*Menu_Processing_Function_Ptr)();

    struct MenuItem
    {
        unsigned int  number;
        const char *  text;
        Menu_Processing_Function_Ptr p_processing_function;
    };

    MenuItem menu[1] =
    {
        {1, "Completely random", completelyRandom}

    };

public:
    Menu();
void completelyRandom(); // no longer throws an error
};
```